# Apply arbitrary shape to a View

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to "shape" a View using a custom path rather than a standard square/oval/etc. shapes?

The high level task is mapping an image of a human body. I want make various areas of it clickable. The idea to use and ImageView to display it the body and then put transparent views on top of it to handle click events. So for instance I would have a view shaped to cover left arm area of the image to catch click event on that arm and nothing else.

If that doesn't work, I was thinking I could use a whole bunch of small square shaped views instead of a single custom shaped one to cover one area, but that seems pretty messy. Or perhaps there is an alternative approach?

Comment: Could you use a WebView with an imagemap?

Comment: @AleksG Hmm perhaps... though the map will be semi-dynamic, and I am not sure that changing HTML will be a whole lot better than my messy solution.